# Android: ImageView with centerCrop scale has not the same behavior on 4.1.1 and 4.4.4 (Android SDK)

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I use this layout to show an image in my `RecyclerView`:

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

I load a picture with Glide library like that:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(my_url)
    .skipMemoryCache(true)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_medium_wide_picture)
    .crossFade()
    .into(contentHolder.mImageView);
```

The height of `ImageView` is computed during **the viewholder creation** according the width screen:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = MyApplication.getInstance().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = Math.round(metrics.widthPixels * Defines.IMAGE_HEIGHT_RATIO);
```

The result is perfect on 4.4.4 Android version:

[image]

But on 4.1.1 Android version the result expected is bad:

[image]

Thanks by advance guys for your help!

Comment: Please change layout_width value = wrap_content. & check it..

Answer (score 0):

You just can use `centerCrop` of Glide and remove the calculation of height based on width.

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(my_url)
    .skipMemoryCache(true)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_medium_wide_picture)
    .crossFade()
    .centerCrop() // Use centerCrop here
    .into(contentHolder.mImageView);
```